# Why does my car's manual tell you not to sleep in your car with the windows up?

Tags: safety

''Danger

​

- If you sleep while operating the air conditioner or heater with all the windows closed, You may suffocate to death due to lack of ventilation. When you operate the air conditioner or heater, ventilate frequently.

​

Multiple vents are provided for distributing the air, being force-circulated by HVAC blower, throughout the passenger compartment.''

​

Huh? I've seen many other manuals say this too, all of recent makes. I don't remember seeing these warnings on older cars. Did something happen?

Comment: You seem to be fascinated by car ventilation, would you like to share with us why that is?

Answer (score 2):

To have the air conditioning or the heater working, the engine would need to be running.  Presumably while you are sleeping, the car is stationary, therefore exhaust fumes will likely be getting drawn into the car.  Carbon monoxide poisoning can build up slowly and is not noticeable.  Therefore there is a chance you will wake up dead.

Nothing has changed with the cars.  The only thing that has changed is that car manufacturers are more aware of being sued for not warning people not to do foolish things.